# How do I position a ContextMenuStrip underneath a link label?

Tags: c#, winforms

My form has a link label *llInventory* and ContextMenuStrip *cmsInventory*. When I **left click** on the link label the contextmenustrip should open right underneath of link label. So I have written code to position the contextMenuStrip but it still displays it at the top left corner of the screen, here is the code

```
        private void llInventory_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
           // llInventory.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            //llInventory.ForeColor = Control.
            Point p = new Point(this.llInventory.Location.X, this.llInventory.Location.Y + llInventory.Height);
            cmsInventory.PointToScreen(p);
            cmsInventory.Show();
        }
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this [`Show(Point)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz0wbhy2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
cmsInventory.Show(cmsInventory.PointToScreen(p));
```

Or you could use [`Show(Control, Point)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71tzk45y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload to position the contextmenustrip relative to the specified control location.